# rectForHeaderInSection doesn't update has tableview scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cgrect

I have a plain tableview with several sections, each with a section header.  I am trying to recreate the effect of bumping a header out of the way when a new header touches it, but I want to do it lower down on the table, not when it touches the top of the screen/tableview.  I want to detect when the section header gets to a certain point on the screen.

I have implemented:

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    CGRect headerRect = [tableView rectForHeaderInSection:0];
    NSLog(@"%f",headerRect.origin.y);
}
```

But as the tableview scrolls, the rect doesn't update to the current location of the header.  I have tried using `tableview.contentOffset.y` but each time I use the tableview there is a different amount of cells in each section so I can't reliably know when the header will reach the right point with this method.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yep, that method name is a lie. I wish I had a good answer but I ran into the same problem and never figured out why.

Comment: Ya it kind of sucks.  I figured out a work around using the content offset and resizing the tableview as it scrolls, but it is a hack at best...a workable hack but a hack